# Firebase Query each node Names

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

[My Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6C8w.jpg)

Hello, How could i get each nodes Names into my angularJs App (I only need the name P1 and the name P2 to display into a html select) using AngularFire or AngularJs?

I've tried the shallow system but can't make it work !

This is how i get the node data actually, it works very well :

```
$scope.data = $firebaseArray(ref.child('prescriptions').child(uid).child(myNodeName));
```

Now i need to get each nodes names (Like P1, P2 or whatever), and will display it into a select !

I need to populate my select dropdown with the names of my nodes (like P1... P2 , P3 or whatever they are called ...)

Comment: I maybe have a piste with this :https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/haschildren.html but dont know how to use forEach() to enumerate p1 and p2

Comment: For a next question: don't post a screenshot of your JSON structure, but post your actual JSON instead. You can easily get it from your Firebase dashboard by clicking the Export button.

Answer (score 1):

A little hard to follow what you are asking, but I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
$scope.data = $firebaseArray(ref.child('prescriptions').child(uid));
```

And then in your html you can use an ng-repeat to populate the list:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="d in data">{{d}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot i will try this and let you know, thank really a lot for your time

Comment: Hello, finally, it works, but i've had to add this to your line : <li ng-repeat="d in data">{{d.$id}}</li> to be able to list "p1" and "p2". Thank infinitly ! have a really nice day hope i will be able to help people later